# Justified Text with central alignment in android

Tags: android, textview, center

Hello everyone, i am working on android application in which i am showing some text using `TextView` with central alignment on the screen. But the problem is that the text is not properly justified on the screen. This is the xml code which i am using for showing text with central alignment on the screen. Please help me for doing this.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Mana addd asdwd ekff fec greq crrq grooe cieurnf covhrpw cjcneie ejducbc ueiche deidhe idhcecm ekwp ww"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This library will provide you a way to justify text.

Compatible for Android 2.2 to 5.X

https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center align text, use `android:gravity="center"` as follows:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lastMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Mana addd asdwd ekff fec greq crrq grooe cieurnf covhrpw cjcneie ejducbc ueiche deidhe idhcecm ekwp ww"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```